# selenium webdriver: Where did storedVars go?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

We're using Selenium stand alone RC server 2.3.0.  We have a bunch of Selenium tests that make reference to the "storedVars" global array variable, e.g. ...

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['vlpSource'].match(storedVars['M37Regex']) != null</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

However, the webdriver implementation, of which we create an instance like this ...

```
     final InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
     selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
```

doesn't recognize storedVars anymore (e.g. the call to "selenium.getEval("storedVars")" will return null.  What can we do to create another storedVar instance for use in our tests we are converting from HTML?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Try selenium.getEval("return storedVars;");

Answer (score 1):

You need a `return`

```
selenium.getEval("return storedVars;");
```